# 400 Error on Django Form

Tags: python, django

I am working on expanding the official django tutorial's poll app. I am in the process of creating profile functionality, where users can register, and edit profile information.

Form is rendering correctly, but when I actually submit info to update the profile info, I get a bad request (400) error.

This is what I see in the console:

```
[02/Feb/2015 12:02:42] "GET /polls/edit_profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3394
[02/Feb/2015 12:02:55] "POST /polls/edit_profile/ HTTP/1.1" 400 26
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

main/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(selfself, request, user):
        return '/polls/'

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
)
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^add_poll/$', views.add_poll, name='add_poll'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    url(r'^profile_page/$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_page'),
    url(r'^edit_profile/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
)
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date',)

forms.DateInput.input_type="date"
forms.DateTimeInput.input_type="datetime-local"
```

views.py

```
class ProfileView(generic.TemplateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'polls/profile_page.html'

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('polls:profile_page')
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'polls/edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

edit_profile.html

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Edit Profile{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

<h3>Current Name: {{ user.userprofile.first_name }} {{ user.userprofile.last_name }}</h3>
<h3>Birth-Date: {{ user.userprofile.birth_date }}

<br><br/>

<form action="/polls/edit_profile/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My view is pretty much the basic handling in the Django documentation, I am wondering if I am messing something up with the urls.py, or if my action variable for edit_html is incorrect?

Thoughts as well as any advice on improving what I have laid out is very welcomed. I think I have provided all relevant info, but let me know if there is something else I can provide.

Cheers

Comment: Does the 400 error include any information? Usually the errors provide the reason as well, which would make this much easier to debug.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have included what shows up in the console. As for the browser, I only get Bad Request (400) showing up.

Comment: What do you have in `settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS`? A bad request is often down to server config rather than your view logic.

Comment: My `settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` - e.g. the default setting.

Comment: Can you show your main urls.py as well? Your edit_profile view doesn't return a 400 - usually those happen in class based views when you don't define the or POST methods - so it seems likely that another view is catching your request.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have included the main urls.py file in an edit.

Comment: Friendly suggestion: get in the habit of using the `url` template tag (i.e. `<form action="/polls/edit_profile/" method="post">` would be `<form action="{% url 'polls:edit_profile' %}" method="post">`) It'll save you some hair pulling down the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're using `HttpResponseRedirect` incorrectly.

It should be:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('profile_page/')
```

I don't think it will render the url name (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

If you would like to be able to redirect by the url name (which is the correct way of doing it) use the shortcut `redirect`

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('polls:profile_page')
```

see docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect